# How to check if mysql queries succeeded

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

After executing a couple of mysql queries, how can I determine if all where successful?

I know I can build an array with data ( `mysql_error()` ) from each `mysql_query` and then analyze the array, but isn't a better way? Because `mysql_affected_rows()` isn't the appropriate function to help in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "successful"? Whether the query succeeded without errors?

Comment: @deceze, I don't think "successful" can have another meaning but "the action succeeded with no errors"

Comment: It could also be "it updated the correct rows" or any number of other things, especially since you also mentioned `mysql_affected_rows`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$unsuccessful = 0;

function query($query)
{
    mysql_query($query) or $GLOBALS['unsuccessful']++;
}

// -------------------------
// USAGE:
// -------------------------

query("UPDATE yourTable SET field1 = 'value'");
query("invalid query 1");
query("invalid query 2");
query("UPDATE yourTable SET field2 = 'value'");

if($GLOBALS['unsuccessful'] > 0) 
    echo $GLOBALS['unsuccessful'] .' queries was unsuccessful.'; // prints "2 queries was unsuccessful"
```

Comment: Cool idea, it's really interesting